# Can i declare a variable and assign a value later?

Tags: php, variables

can i declare a variable and assign a value later ?

Is this feasable somehow ?

```
$redirect = "recording.php?album=$albumid";


$albumid = 4;
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien answers, both long and short, go in the Answers section, not the Comments section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't do what you're asking.  There are alternatives, though.

```
$redirect = "recording.php?album=";

$albumid = 4;

$redirect .= $albumid;

// use your $redirect var here...
```

Does this suffice?

Comment: If you want to have a constant, another option would be to use some sort of place-holder like `recording.php?album={0}` and then do a `$newString = str_replace("{0}", $albumid, $redirect);` .  This might be more ideal, so you can have multiple variables in your string like {0} and {1} thus being able to update values in the middle of the string and not only at the end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

If you want more flexibility then you can wrap your string in a function like so:

```
function getRedirect($albumid)
{
    return "recording.php?album=$albumid";
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
$redirect = getRedirect(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Negative... value has to be assigned to variable before use or it will return null.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant do it this way . 
Instead just append album id to redirect url .

```
        $redirect = "recording.php?album=";
        $albumid = 4;
        $redirect .= $albumid;
```

Happy coding :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
$albumid = "";
$redirect = "recording.php?album=$albumid";
$albumid = 4;
```

actually when you use $redirect = "recording.php?album=$albumid"; that time it get error to undefined variable name . so, firstly set that variable to null.. and after that change the value as per need.

Can this helps you ?

Comment: But surely this doesn't achieve what the SO is looking for i.e. this will not dynamically apply the value 4 to the redirect. Variable $redirect will have value "recording.php?album=" variable $albumid will have value 4. Changing the value of $albumid after the assignment to $redirect does not alter $redirect.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. It is possible to using Ajax or java-script. Or as @FoolishSeth suggest , function can be use for this.

Comment: I think the function works but is overkill I would follow adam's and Aditi's answers.